# mongodb v3 driver vc++ community addition linker errors

Tags: mongodb, visual-c++, driver, mongo-cxx-driver

I'm getting the following linker errors in types.hpp while compiling in vc++ 2017. How shall i solve them ?

Below is the code I'm tyring to compile in vc++.

Additional directories included.

E:\boost_1_61_0-bin-msvc-all-32-64\boost_1_61_0;E:\nosql_db\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.1.3\include\mongocxx\v_noabi;E:\nosql_db\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.1.3\include\bsoncxx\v_noabi;E:\nosql_db\mon-c-driver\include\libbson-1.0;E:\nosql_db\mon-c-driver\include\libmongoc-1.0;%(AdditionalDependencies)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <bsoncxx/builder/stream/document.hpp>
#include <bsoncxx/json.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/client.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/instance.hpp>

using bsoncxx::builder::stream::document;

int main()
{
    mongocxx::instance inst{};
    mongocxx::client conn{ mongocxx::uri{} };

    bsoncxx::builder::stream::document document{};

    auto collection = conn["testdb"]["testcollection"];
    document << "hello" << "world";

    collection.insert_one(document.view());
    auto cursor = collection.find({});

    for (auto&& doc : cursor) {
        std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(doc) << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}


everity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0145   member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_double::type_id" may not be initialized  textapp e:\nosql_db\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.1.3\include\bsoncxx\v_noabi\bsoncxx\types.hpp   86  
Error (active)  E0145   member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_utf8::type_id" may not be initialized    textapp e:\nosql_db\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.1.3\include\bsoncxx\v_noabi\bsoncxx\types.hpp   111 
Error (active)  E0145   member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_document::type_id" may not be initialized    textapp e:\nosql_db\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.1.3\include\bsoncxx\v_noabi\bsoncxx\types.hpp   149 
Error (active)  E0145   member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_array::type_id" may not be initialized   textapp e:\nosql_db\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.1.3\include\bsoncxx\v_noabi\bsoncxx\types.hpp   181 
Error (active)  E0145   member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_binary::type_id" may not be initialized  textapp e:\nosql_db\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.1.3\include\bsoncxx\v_noabi\bsoncxx\types.hpp   206 
Error (active)  E0145   member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_undefined::type_id" may not be initialized   textapp e:\nosql_db\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.1.3\include\bsoncxx\v_noabi\bsoncxx\types.hpp   230 
Error (active)  E0145   member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_oid::type_id" may not be initialized textapp e:\nosql_db\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.1.3\include\bsoncxx\v_noabi\bsoncxx\types.hpp   246 
Error (active)  E0145   member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_bool::type_id" may not be initialized    textapp e:\nosql_db\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.1.3\include\bsoncxx\v_noabi\bsoncxx\types.hpp   264 
Error (active)  E0145   member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_date::type_id" may not be initialized    textapp e:\nosql_db\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.1.3\include\bsoncxx\v_noabi\bsoncxx\types.hpp   289 
Error (active)  E0145   member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_null::type_id" may not be initialized    textapp e:\nosql_db\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.1.3\include\bsoncxx\v_noabi\bsoncxx\types.hpp   350 
Error (active)  E0145   member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_regex::type_id" may not be initialized   textapp e:\nosql_db\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.1.3\include\bsoncxx\v_noabi\bsoncxx\types.hpp   366 
Error (active)  E0145   member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_dbpointer::type_id" may not be initialized   textapp e:\nosql_db\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.1.3\include\bsoncxx\v_noabi\bsoncxx\types.hpp   402 
Error (active)  E0145   member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_code::type_id" may not be initialized    textapp e:\nosql_db\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.1.3\include\bsoncxx\v_noabi\bsoncxx\types.hpp   421 
Error (active)  E0145   member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_symbol::type_id" may not be initialized  textapp e:\nosql_db\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.1.3\include\bsoncxx\v_noabi\bsoncxx\types.hpp   462 
Error (active)  E0145   member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_codewscope::type_id" may not be initialized  textapp e:\nosql_db\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.1.3\include\bsoncxx\v_noabi\bsoncxx\types.hpp   500 
Error (active)  E0145   member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_int32::type_id" may not be initialized   textapp e:\nosql_db\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.1.3\include\bsoncxx\v_noabi\bsoncxx\types.hpp   533 
Error (active)  E0145   member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_timestamp::type_id" may not be initialized   textapp e:\nosql_db\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.1.3\include\bsoncxx\v_noabi\bsoncxx\types.hpp   562 
Error (active)  E0145   member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_int64::type_id" may not be initialized   textapp e:\nosql_db\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.1.3\include\bsoncxx\v_noabi\bsoncxx\types.hpp   581 
Error (active)  E0145   member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_decimal128::type_id" may not be initialized  textapp e:\nosql_db\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.1.3\include\bsoncxx\v_noabi\bsoncxx\types.hpp   606 
Error (active)  E0145   member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_minkey::type_id" may not be initialized  textapp e:\nosql_db\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.1.3\include\bsoncxx\v_noabi\bsoncxx\types.hpp   637 
Error (active)  E0145   member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_maxkey::type_id" may not be initialized  textapp e:\nosql_db\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.1.3\include\bsoncxx\v_noabi\bsoncxx\types.hpp   653 
Error   LNK1107 invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x398   textapp E:\nosql_db\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.1.3\bin\mongocxx.dll    1
```

Steps followed for installing the driver.

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=E:\\nosql_db\\mongo-c-driver" "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release"
msbuild.exe /p:Configuration=Release ALL_BUILD.vcxproj
msbuild.exe /p:Configuration=Release INSTALL.vcxproj
cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" "-DENABLE_SSL=WINDOWS" "-DENABLE_SASL=SSPI" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=E:\\nosql_db\\mongo-c-driver1" "-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=E:\\nosql_db\\mongo-c-driver" "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release"
msbuild.exe /p:Configuration=Release ALL_BUILD.vcxproj
msbuild.exe /p:Configuration=Release INSTALL.vcxproj
cmake.exe -G "Visual Studio 14 Win64" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=E:\\nosql_db\\mongo-cxx-driver1 -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=E:\\nosql_db\\mon-c-driver -DBOOST_ROOT=E:\\boost_1_65_1
msbuild.exe ALL_BUILD.vcxproj
msbuild.exe INSTALL.vcxproj
```

Then added additional libraries in vc++ configuration.

```
E:\nosql_db\mongo-cxx-driver1\include\bsoncxx\v_noabi;E:\nosql_db\mongo-cxx-driver1\include\mongocxx\v_noabi;E:\nosql_db\mon-c-driver\include\libbson-1.0;E:\nosql_db\mon-c-driver\include\libmongoc-1.0;

E:\nosql_db\mongo-cxx-driver1\bin\mongocxx.dll;E:\nosql_db\mongo-cxx-driver1\bin\bsoncxx.dll;E:\nosql_db\mon-c-driver\bin\libbson-1.0.dll;E:\nosql_db\mon-c-driver\bin\libmongoc-1.0.dll;
```

Here are my linker settings:

```
   /MANIFEST /LTCG:incremental /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"E:\workouts\cpp\textapp\textapp\x64\Release\textapp.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "mongocxx.dll" "bsoncxx.dll" "libbson-1.0.dll" "libmongoc-1.0.dll" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /IMPLIB:"E:\nosql_db\mongo-cxx-driver1\bin\mongocxx.dll;E:\nosql_db\mongo-cxx-driver1\bin\bsoncxx.dll;E:\nosql_db\mon-c-driver\bin\libbson-1.0.dll;E:\nosql_db\mon-c-driver\bin\libmongoc-1.0.dll;" /DEBUG:FULL /MACHINE:X64 /OPT:REF /INCREMENTAL:NO /PGD:"E:\workouts\cpp\textapp\textapp\x64\Release\textapp.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"x64\Release\textapp.exe.intermediate.manifest" /OPT:ICF /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"E:\nosql_db\mongo-cxx-driver1\lib\bsoncxx.lib" /LIBPATH:"E:\nosql_db\mongo-cxx-driver1\lib\libbsoncxx.lib" /LIBPATH:"E:\nosql_db\mongo-cxx-driver1\lib\libmongocxx.lib" /LIBPATH:"E:\nosql_db\mongo-cxx-driver1\lib\mongocxx.lib" /LIBPATH:"E:\nosql_db\mon-c-driver\lib\bson-1.0.lib" /LIBPATH:"E:\nosql_db\mon-c-driver\lib\mongoc-1.0.lib" /TLBID:1
```

Comment: That is a strange error. These are static constexpr values. And those don't look like MSVC errors. Do you have some sort of static analysis or lint thing enabled here? Also, please state what version of the driver you are building.

Comment: Also, that LNK1107 error is pretty weird. mongocxx.dll is corrupt?

Comment: Microsoft community edition 2017. I didnt enabled any static analysis tools, nor i dont know how to enable them. if so how shall i disable static analysis. mongo-c-driver-1.8.0 and mongo-cxx-driver-r3.1.3. Added the steps followed for installing the driver.